# Как вытащить сумму значений столбца таблицы А, для каждого значения таблицы B?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы.

```sql
Таблица А:
|id|a_id|value|
| 1|   1|    8|
| 2|   1|    5|
| 3|   3|    2|
| 4|   3|    0|
| 5|   3|    7|
| 6|   4|    3|
| 7|   4|    1|
| 8|   2|    0|
| 9|   1|    6|
|10|   2|    3|
```

```sql
Таблица B:
|id|str|
| 1| qw|
| 2| er|
| 3| ty|
| 4| ui|
```

Сумму столбца **values** можно узнать так:

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(value)
FROM Таблица_A

Output: 35
```

Чтобы узнать все записи по определенному столбцу **str** со значением **qw**:

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(value)
FROM Таблица_A AS a,
     Таблица_B AS b
WHERE a.a_id = b.id
AND b.id = 1

Output: 19
```

Собственно вопрос - возможно ли написать запрос, который сам будет перебирать значения id таблицы B(*..AND b.id ={от 1 до 4}*)? Чтобы в конечном итоге вывод после запроса был примерно таким:

```sql
|sum|b.str|
|  8|   qw|
|  0|   er|
|  9|   rt|
...
```

Или хотя бы просто:

```sql
|sum|
| 19|
|  3|
|  9|
...
```

P.S.:Собственно на питоне все это реализовано. Нужно именно запросом(sql скриптом).

Comment: SELECT b.str, sum(a.value) FROM Таблица_A AS a, Таблица_B AS b WHERE a.a_id = b.id group by b.str

Comment: @becouse, большое спасибо. Оказалось все просто, пора нормально изучить sql :D

Comment: Ибо это путь истинного джедая.

Comment: @becouse, оставь решение не в комментах, а в ответе, чтобы я выбрал как правильное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так решается через агрегатные функции

```
SELECT
  b.str,
  SUM(a.value)
FROM Таблица_A AS a,
     Таблица_B AS b
WHERE a.a_id = b.id
GROUP BY b.str
```